# which is better solution for develop `meteor Js` app?

Tags: html, meteor

I need help for i am new to `meteorjs`. I am  develop a e-commerce site for multi devices.
1.Two html files are write separate  and load which device is  used load that web-app.
2.If the user login into our app by using mobile how to load mobile app using **meteor Js**.
Please suggest me If the above two statements is wrong and tell me how to approach me .

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Meteor servers all your client files (css, js, and templates converted into js) together at first request. Therefore you won't be able to send files selectively.

The Meteor way is setting up templates and showing/hiding (rendering) those templates according to your criteria.

One of the most selected routes for mobile is to use a responsive design in your ui with a mobile-first and feature detection strategy, but if you must, there device detection libraries in [atmosphere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/), the meteor 3rd party package repository.

There actually is an ongoing discussion about this at the [meteor-talk google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/ku7kvNJp8ek).